# Connection timeout when using backup module

Tags: .htaccess, backups

Currently running Drupal 7.65. Trying to update to 7.67 due to the security update.

I've been trying to run the backup & migrate module to back-up my site, but even when doing partial back-ups (e.g. just of the CiviCRM database), the site times out after 180s and I get this error message:

[image: REQUEST TIMEOUT: This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.]

I spoke to our host who increased the disk quota by 2000MB but that didn't do anything.

I then added the following code to the htaccess file in the root folder, through CPanel:

```
    # Increase connection timeout. 
    <IfModule mod_php5.c> 
    php_value max_execution_time 300 
    </IfModule>
```

However it's still timing out after 180s. (Rather than 300s that the code should be setting.)

I need to back-up the site before I do the security update, can anyone advise why this is timing out and what I can do?

It's not a massive site... disk usage is 7GB out of 12GB, and MySQL disk usage is 2.2GB out of 7GB. Is there something I'm missing to make sure the code I put into the htaccess file is actually implemented...?

Thanks in advance - please let me know if you need more info, IT is not my area of expertise!

Comment: Give this a try, it works for me on a server not set up by me, enable or disable any module, then hit the backup button, for some reason it doesn't time out for me when I do that.

Comment: @NoSssweat thanks for your reply! I tried disabling a module and backing up the CiviCRM database but it still timed out after 180s.

Comment: You could try increasing your PHP memory limit. If your host uses C-Panel, you should be able to perform the backup from the C-Panel rather than from Drupal.